# RxJava - Start one Observable when other one finish

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I have two Observables with different generic types: Observable o1 and Observable o2

I was defined to o1 the onComplet() and onNext() functions and i want that when this Observable get their finish then the o2 can start.

I tryed the Observable.concat() but they have different types, so this approach doesn't work...

So How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `castAs` before `concatWith` (and `ignoreElements` can be useful too):

```
Observable<T> o1;
Observable<R> o2;

Observable<R> o3 = 
  o1.ignoreElements()
    .castAs(R.class)
    .concatWith(o2);
```

Or if you're working with generic types (thus can't use `R.class`):

```
Observable<R> o3 = ((Observable<R>)(Observable<?>)
  o1.ignoreElements())
    .concatWith(o2);
```

Comment: one more problem: my "R" class is a List<R>. How can I cast a List with its specific generic type?

Comment: Added how to for generic types

Answer (score 0):

Observable has a method called `doOnCompleted` which takes an `Action0` (a zero-argument function) and returns a new Observable which performs the action when it completes normally. Maybe you can use this to achieve what you want?

```
o1.doOnCompleted(() -> {
    // Start o2.
});
```

Comment: So how are you starting o2 and what does the questioner want the overall stream to return? Calling subscribe in an onComplete action verges on an anti-pattern in rxjava when appropriate operators are available to do everything with one subscription.